# Що таке "баська"?

Tags: значення-слів, діалектизми

Нещодавно почув слово "баська". Однак, не можу зрозуміти його значення, адже його немає в СУМ-11 та СУМ-20. А в Гугл пише, що "[баська](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/1042-baska.html)" - це назва вівці.

Гадаю, варто зазначити, що це слово я почув на Вербну неділю і воно точно пов'язане з вербою. Проте не зрозумів чи люди так називають вербу чи її гілля? Чи, можливо, це якась діалектна назва "[котиків](http://sum.in.ua/s/kotyk)" (див. 3-є значення)?

Comment: Так і є.... гілочки верби із бруньками.

Comment: Здається, це запитання було [вилучено автоматично через неактивність](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) (імовірно, «if the question is more than 365 days old, and…») — я повернув його.

Answer (score 2):

У коментарях на фейсбуці практично відповіли на це запитання:

- [Stosja Kornilenko](https://facebook.com/ukrse/posts/pfbid0grtGP2F7Fe4gqLh9Ak9n2YD2HNCFhc6M6LHihwbF6zSi7AjCFA39SZ3hJJfGwfVSl?comment_id=3649688531823833):

  > Це є такий типу букетик з гілочок, які продають на вербну неділю:
  > [image]
- [Michael Broshko](https://facebook.com/ukrse/posts/pfbid0grtGP2F7Fe4gqLh9Ak9n2YD2HNCFhc6M6LHihwbF6zSi7AjCFA39SZ3hJJfGwfVSl?comment_id=3649688531823833&reply_comment_id=1391817438245808):

  > Баська — це брунька верби, вербові котики. Тиждень перед Великоднем в церкві освячуються гілки верби або баськи на діалекті частини заходу України.
  > «Баська б'є, баська б'є, а за тиждень Паска є» — так приговорюють люди, виходячи з церкви і за жартома б'ючи один одного.

У наявності такої приповідки можна швидко переконатися пошуком, наприклад так каже [стаття «Вербна неділя: історія свята, повір'я та традиції» Ірини Мелешко на сайті інформаційної агенції «Вголос»](https://vgolos.ua/news/verbna-nedilya-istoriya-svyata-povir-ya-ta-tradiciyi_1418834.html):

> В Галичині кажуть ще й так:
> <…>
> «Баська б'є, баська  б'є, а за тиждень Пасха є!».

Також слово [*баська* подано в «Словнику українських наукових і народних назв судинних рослин» Юрія Кобова 2004 року видання](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0&dicts=14&highlight=on) як наддністрянська діалектна назва для всієї рослини Salix purpurea L. (відомої як верба пурпурова, верба червона й під іншими назвами), з посиланням на 5-й том збірки «Зібрані статті. Діялектологія» Олекси Горбача (Мюнхен, 1993, 665 сторінок).

Comment: @Yola, так там усього лише повторюють приповідку «Баська б'є, баська б'є, а за тиждень Пасха є!». Я просто хотів пересвідчитися, що не лише один Michael Broshko її наводить. Але, гаразд, переніс.